# Clicking a Link in td with Watir

Tags: css, ruby, html-table, watir

I'm trying to click an image in  with a Watir script.  Here's the source code for what I'm trying to click:

```
<td align="right">
   <a onclick="confirmAndSubmit('Exit application?', 'saveAndExit')"
   onmouseover="style.cursor='hand'">
   <img src="/images/exitBlue.gif" align="bottom"></img>
   </a>
</td>
```

Watir seems to be unable to locate the element based on my code.  It seems like I have to write sort of a complex statement with the arguments.  I've tried

```
$b.td(:img, "src='/images/exitBlue.gif'").click
```

as well as

```
$b.element(:css, "td[onClick='confirmAndSubmit('Exit application?', 'saveAndExit')']").click
```

but nothing seems to locate the data in the table.  Any suggestions on how to go about clicking this?

Comment: Try the `image` method?  For example: `b.image(:src, '/images/exitBlue.gif').click`

Comment: Same error: Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["img"], :src=>"/images/exitBlue.gif"}

Comment: Shwheelz, you might need to provide more details about your page then. @orde solution works given just the html you have provided. There is likely another reason causing the problem. Try going through the different ideas listed on [my blog](http://jkotests.wordpress.com/unable-to-locate-element/).

Comment: The element I'm trying to select is contained within:   <body><form name="foo"><table><tr><td><div id="bar"><table><tr><td>Posted Source Code Here</closeAllTags>

Comment: I tried to troubleshoot based on your blog posts:    $b.form(:name, "foo").div(:id, "bar").image(:src, "/images/exitBlue.gif").click

but can't locate the form either.  I'm really stumped as to what the problem could be.  If I do a when_present, the script just hangs.  I know it's on the right page because I'm printing $b.title to the console before it tries to find the link.

Comment: Did you verify that the form is not in a frame or iframe?

Comment: Yes, there is no frame or iframe present in the source code of that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with a bit of trial and error.  As mentioned in the comments, the image was inside nested tables.  I targeted the div inside the first table and was able to get to it.  The element.flash method was invaluable in troubleshooting.  The code I was originally using was only getting inside the first cell of the table and therefore couldn't find the image.  The code that worked for me:

```
$b.div(:id, "bar").table.td(:index => 1).image.click_no_wait
```